# Close spark context started via Celery task in a django app

Tags: pyspark, django-rest-framework, celery, python-3.6

I am using Pyspark along with Celery in a Django app. So the flow of my code is as follows:
1. Put a POST request to upload a file (large file).
2. Django handles the request and loads the file to hdfs. This large file in hdfs is read by pyspark to load it into the cassandra.
3. This upload is handled by Celery (from reading file to cassandra upload). Celery starts the process in the background and starts a spark context to start the upload.
4. The data gets loaded to cassandra, **but the spark context which was created via the celery does not stop even after using spark.stop()** when the load is complete.

project -> celery.py

```
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

tasks.py

```
import celery
from project.celery import app
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class uploadfile():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cluster = Cluster(getattr(settings, "CASSANDRA_IP", ""))
        self.session = self.cluster.connect()
    def start_spark(self):
        self.spark = SparkSession.builder.master(getattr(settings,'SPARK_MASTER', settings.SPARK_MASTER))\
                                .appName('Load CSV to Cassandra')\
                                .config('spark.jars', self.jar_files_path)\
                                .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', getattr(settings,'SPARK_CASSANDRA_CONNECTION_HOST','0.0.0.0'))\
                                .getOrCreate()
    def spark_stop(self):
        self.spark.stop()
    def file_upload(self):
        self.start_spark()
        df = self.spark.read.csv(file_from_hdfs)
        # do some operation on the dataframe
        # self.session.create_cassandra_table_if_does_not_exist
        df.write.format('org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra').\
                    .option('table',table_name)\
                    .option('keyspace',keyspace)\
                    .mode('append').save()
        self.spark_stop()  <<<-------------------- This does not close the spark context

@task(name="api.tasks.uploadfile")
def csv_upload():
    # handle request.FILE and upload the file to hdfs
    spark_obj = uploadfile()
    spark_obj.file_upload()
```

calling_task_script.py

```
from task import csv_upload
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class post_it(APIView):
    def post(request):
        csv_upload.delay()
        return Response('success')
```

Comment: Technically it should work, but you can also try `spark.sparkContext.stop()`. How do you come to know the sparkContext hasn't stopped?

Comment: I monitor `jps` processes. Once the entire celery process completes, the spark context still exists. What I assume is, celery does start spark but that spark context is created in some process other than on which the celery process starts. Just an assumption.

Comment: Hey @pissall, I tried `spark.sparkContext.stop()` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you found the solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I am facing the same issue, when Celery task is executed I find that the sparkContext still exists.